# Maximum Likelihood of single observation

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I'm stumped on this problem... I keep getting an undefined answer of having to solve -20 = 0. The likelihood function I get is $e^{-20\alpha}$.

So I have

- $y_i=$ $ \begin{cases} 
        1& w/probability \ p_i \\
        0& w/probability \ 1-p_i 
     \end{cases}$
- And $p_i=1-e^{-\alpha x_i}$, i=1,2,...
- $\alpha>=0$   and $x_i>=0$

If I have a sample of a single observation $(y_1,x_1)=(0,20)$, I am looking for the maximum likelihood of this sample.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- You have a likelihood of $L(\alpha\mid y_1=0) = e^{-20\alpha}$ and you also know $\alpha\ge 0$
- If $e^{-20\alpha}$, which is continuous and differentiable, does not have a turning point for positive $\alpha$, then it is monotonic and will have a maximum either when $\alpha=0$ or when $\alpha \to \infty$, and it is fairly obvious which

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks :)

Comment: Clearly it is 0. Can you confirm my likelihood is right though?

Comment: The likelihood looks right to me, as does $0$